# State Dropdown not coming in Ascending order through DLL

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a dropdown list, for which values comes from the table. But the problem is that it is not coming alphabetically. I want that the name of the city should come alphabetically. Please see the code for your reference.

```
 private void LoadDropDowns()
{
    var states = _careerHelper.GetStates(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
    states.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    ddlState.DataSource = states;
    ddlState.DataBind();
}
```

I am calling the DLL files for the states to render,
Please see the dll code also:-

```
   public List<string> GetStates(string country)
    {
        if (country == "")
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return _rblDataContext.Locations.Where(m => m.CountryName.ToLower() == country.ToLower()).Select(m => m.StateName).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
```

The states values are coming but not in ascending order, I want that to be displayed in Ascending order. I tried putting states.Insert() below DataBind() but it didn't worked. Please help

Comment: Are the values held in a DataTable? If so you could create a DataView and then sort by the column name

Comment: Actually when I comment the whole dll code for GetStates, it is working exactly. And the values is also getting inserted in the DB. is this the correct way ?

Comment: Yes, the values are coming in datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are expecting the data to be sorted when you do not sort anywhere? If you do not explicitly order in your sql-query (which your linq-query results in), then SQL Server (I'm assuming here) will not guarantee any specific order of the results.

To solve this, you need to add an `OrderBy(...)`.

```
return _rblDataContext.Locations
    .Where(m => m.CountryName.ToLower() == country.ToLower())
    .Select(m => m.StateName)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(m => m)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The city is coming by default in ascending order on select of any state, but not the state one. Any other way. I added the data through import in the sql table.

Comment: Actually when I comment the whole dll code for GetStates, it is working exactly. And the values is also getting inserted in the DB. is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the order of the rows via SQL then you can create a DataView for the DataTable like:

```
DataView dvTable = new DataView(DataTableName);
dvTable.Sort = "CityName asc/desc"; //asc in the case of this question.

ddlState.DataSource = dvTable;
ddlState.DataValueField = "PK_State";
ddlState.DataTextField = "CityName";
ddlState.DataBind();
```

Comment: Its giving me compilation error for the below line: "DataTableName' does not exist in the current context"
 DataView dvTable = new DataView(DataTableName["Career.Location"]);

Comment: Swap DataTableName with the name of the data table you are using, so if you were using a data set you would use ds.table["TableName"], if you just use table then new DataView(TableName)

Comment: Its giving me this error now:- DataTable must be set prior to using DataView. See my full code:-DataView dvTable = new DataView();
        dvTable.Sort = "StateName asc"; //asc in the case of this question.

        var states = 
        ddlState.DataSource = dvTable;
        ddlState.DataValueField = "StateName";
        ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
        ddlState.DataBind();

Comment: what is in: dvTable = new DataView(*There should be your table name here*)?

Comment: 'MSELibrary.Location' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' giving these error
My table name is "location"

Comment: i have a dll also for it, please see below:        public List<string> GetStates(string country)
        {
            if (country == "")
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                  return _rblDataContext.Locations.Where(m => m.CountryName.ToLower() == country.ToLower()).Select(m => m.StateName).Distinct().ToList();
            }
        }